# How do i implement htmlspecialchars for a textbox value?

Tags: php, wordpress, textbox, htmlspecialchars

Hello i'm currently using a table to input values into a custom meta field. I have a text box called episode title. My problem here is that if the characters ' " are added in the field then everything goes in to chaos. I want to use the htmlspecialchars to input the values as &quot and &#039 instead of ' ".  the below code does not work to covert the characters. Can anyone please help?

```
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="episode_title[]" id="episode_title[]" value="<?php echo ($_POST['episode_title']); ?>" class="title regular-text" style="width: 98%" />
      <span class="description"><?php _e('Title of The Episode.'); ?></span>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to the `htmlspecialchars` call: `ENT_QUOTES` like so:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['episode_title'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>
```

This will enable changing of both the `"` and the `'` quotes

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['episode_title']` is an array, so you need to get the right value from the array and use `htmlspecialchars()` on that value.

Something like:

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['episode_title'][$some_key]); ?>"
```

**Edit:** I am assuming that the `$_POST` array contains the results of the form when it is submitted.

Comment: how do you know episode_title is an array? sounds more like a string to me?

Comment: @dragon112 I am assuming it is the result of the submitted form: `name="episode_title[]"`